# Can Juniper EX series switches terminate a q-in-q interface?

Tags: juniper-ex

Other terms are stacked vlans, provider bridges, s-vlan

If we purchased EX series switches, could they be configured with RVIs to terminate the double tagged frame?

Or, will we require an MX series router?

We get wholesale customers presented as double-tags.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately EX switches cannot terminate double-tagged vlans. You would need a bigger box like the MX or M series with IQ/IQ2 module if sticking with Juniper.

The best you could do with the EX is strip off the outer-tag and push those inner frames to another EX.

Comment: Ghetto solution would be loop cables, to strip vlans. But probably not going to scale, as I suppose @rick won't have small number of top tags.

Comment: I've done that ghetto solution on a number of 3560s. It works, but its messy!

Comment: Haha I looked into the ghetto loops but I need unique double tags per customer. I.e.there may be duplicate inner tags. Need a 4 figure solution, i.e. under 10k. Mikrotik can do it on a $100 router

Comment: Maybe use the mikrotik then?

Comment: Well they have a bad boy 36 core thing with 16 gigs of ram which I'm considering.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the Juniper realm their MX series are the official answer for this, and the lower end versions of the MX80 are similar in cost to Cisco's metro switches.

They used to offer "switch" (-X) versions of the MX cards that had a lower route count and were significantly cheaper, not sure if they still sell them though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos/topics/reference/general/ex-series-l3-protocols-not-supported.html) RVI's aren't supported on EX switches. Is your goal to transport the wholesale customers' stacked VLANs across your network? If so, I'm not sure that using RVI's would be what you'd want to do, since transport is usually the inherent goal in PB, rather than doing Layer3 termination for an S-TAG. You're probably going to want to go with PBB or MPLS/VPLS in order to transport the customer's S-TAG's - the latter two options would still need an MX (I'll defer to the more Juniper-proficient for other options - I believe mellowd has also recommended the M series). Again this is assuming that your goal is transporting your customers' QinQ traffic.

Comment: We are supplying internet using another providers infrastructure and each customer is a unique vlan pair

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when the support started but on the EX4200 platform with the 12.1R4.7 version you can use q-in-q.
On the *vlans* configuration you set the "outer" vlan and then you use the dot1q-tunneling sub-command:

```
set vlans SERVICE-VLAN vlan-id 123
set vlans SERVICE-VLAN interface ae1.0
set vlans SERVICE-VLAN dot1q-tunneling customer-vlans 610
set vlans SERVICE-VLAN dot1q-tunneling customer-vlans 611
```

Under the *ethernet-switching-options* config there's also the global settings for dot1q-tunneling.